# Nginx doesn't send expires headers

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, plesk

I am migrating a site from apache web server and cannot get nginx header expiration work. This is the part of the server block (testing on a subdomain):

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name br.mydomain.com;
    server_name www.br.mydomain.com;
    server_name ipv4.br.mydomain.com;
    server_name localhost;

    # Path for static files
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    #Specify a charset
    charset utf-8;

    # Custom 404 page
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # cache.appcache, your document html and data
    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html|xml|json)$ {
      expires -1;
    #  access_log logs/static.log;
    }

    # Feed
    location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
      expires 1h;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Favicon
    location ~* \.ico$ {
      expires 1w;
      access_log off;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Media: images, video, audio, HTC, WebFonts
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
      expires 60d;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    #location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    #  expires 1y;
    #  access_log off;
    #  add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #}

    # opt-in to the future
    add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
  }
```

Nginx restarts OK, no error messages, but it doesn't change header expiration:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=604800
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Wed, 27 Nov 2013 22:07:55 GMT
Expires:Wed, 04 Dec 2013 22:07:55 GMT
Last-Modified:Mon, 18 Nov 2013 08:34:10 GMT
Server:nginx
X-Powered-By:PleskLin
```

What could be wrong here and prevent setting expiration times?

Thanks!

**UPDATE: Having spent 5 hours in debugging this simple thing I've found the problem:**

after changing the nginx configuration files reloading nginx (/etc/init.d/nginx reload) is not enough - **the nginx services on Plesk panel should be restarted** (off/on). Otherwise, the changes will not be applied.